# Application fails to start when using Azure website package deployment

Tags: azure, deployment

We've recently switched to using Azure package deployment for our sites (https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84) - and it's great!  It's a great feature which has radically simplified our deployments.  However we have a second site which will not run when packaged (but does run when not packaged).

We followed the standard procedure for setting a site to run from a package;

- created the folder /data/SitePackages from ftp,
- drop the package in there along with the packagename.txt file
- set the App config setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE=1

However we receive "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." on the homepage, and any other subsequent page we receive "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.".  It's as though the site isn't loading the package at all?  Azure Log stream show's "HTTP Error 401.3 - Unauthorized" on the home page and a standard 404 for anything else.

From the Azure portal, if i click console and ls to see a directory listing of the files it thinks it's running all I see is a single file;

```
FAILED TO DOWNLOAD ZIP FILE.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was the azure portal not loading the package.  Looking at our TeamCity setup, the step which generates the "packagename.txt" file has a typo, so the zip file Azure was trying to load did not exist.